# Angular Error 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this problem with my other project. So I made a new one and as simple as posible.

test.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Full error :

'mat-form-field' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)

Comment: That's strange. Can you try adding `MatInputModule` to your `imports` array in the module? I say this because you're using `matInput` directive.

Comment: try rebuilding the app (delete any ```build``` or ```dist``` directory)

Comment: Hi, If you have your local server running and in between if you have add angular material, I suggest to restart the server.

if this can not solve your problem then please make stackblitz and post link here, because by looking it seems correct.

Comment: Fix ! I used angular 8.0.2 and angular/material 8.2.3. I updatet angular cli to latest and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Fix !

I used angular 8.0.2 and angular/material 8.2.3.

I updatet angular cli to latest and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I was the same issue, but using **Angular Language Service** extension for **VS Code**. Problem was resolved by installing previous version of plugin.

Extension major version equals to major version @angular/language-service:

- "13.3.4" contains @angular/language-service@13.3.8,
- "14.2.0" contains @angular/language-service@14.2.0
- "15.2.1" contains @angular/language-service@15.2.7

For my angular@5 project "v13.3.4" version works well.

[image]